# Incremental index synchronization instead of full reindex in Magento 2

Tags: elasticsearch, magento2

Basically Magento 2 has **reindex** functionality through `php bin/magento indexer:reindex`. We are going to have millions of products, so full reindex would be very slow for us. We disabled index update after every single product import. We do import via plain SQL inserts outside Magento 2 Bootstrap. My question is - is it possible to have an incremental index synchronization instead of full reindex. Thanks in advance.

I looked at Magento 2 CLI documentation & didn't find any possibility to have flags in `indexer:reindex` responsible for incremental behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Magento has 2 indexation methods. Index on save, and Index on Schedule. See more [here](https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/commerce-operations/implementation-playbook/best-practices/maintenance/indexer-configuration.html?lang=en)

In your case the most logical solution would be to use the Index on Schedule. When configured on schedule Magento will create Mysql Triggers to detect
changes made to catalog_product_entity tables. So if you uses php code to update the product or SQL queries as you intend to the change will be
detected.

You can see these "change logs" in various tables such as `catalog_product_category_cl`.

You therefore do not need to do any manual operations, Magento will automatically reindex what is needed base on the changes you do. We run 10M product stores and indeed a full reindex is extremely slow, but we nearly never do them.

That said there is one important point, "LOCKS". As said Magento will reindex automatically, but if your import is still running there is a risk that your import
tries to write data into locked sections of the database as the import will lock them. You should therefore disable the indexation process while you are
importing and enable it again once the import is finished. That way the changes will be logged but the index will only be updated after.

You can achieve this either by completely stopping the crons or with a plugin on `Magento\Indexer\Model\Indexer` to prevent it from being executed.

Comment: Thank's for your answer. Can you tell if multi threading works in community edition of Magento 2 (we use 2.4.5)? I did several benchmarks with full reindex and didn't see it works. For example in context of resources there is no difference between MAGE_INDEXER_THREADS_COUNT=30 php -f bin/magento indexer:reindex catalogsearch_fulltext & php -f bin/magento indexer:reindex catalogsearch_fulltext
Thanks in advance

Comment: You need to have pcntl_fork php extension installed for that to work. If you are running differential imports, and you products don't change much you won't need to run multiple threads, it will reindex only what it needs.

Also pay attention to the number of threads; even 2 threads will use alot of resources on the mysql/mariadb which can cause other issues.

Comment: Let me clarify. I already implemented MySQL stored procedure that does product import outside Magento 2 Bootstrap API & can be executed in multiple threads. Right now I'm talking about synchronization with Elastic Search. I'm trying to do full re-index in multiple threading. Official Magento docs say that multi threading can be done through  MAGE_INDEXER_THREADS_COUNT parameter in CLI. Am I correctly understand that in order to actually have multi threading in synchronization with Elasticsearch I need to install pcntl_fork php extension?

Comment: Sorry for the stupid question I'm Ruby on Rails developer & Magento 2 is just the part of our system

Comment: Hello, yes you need to have the php pcntl_fork extension installed.